# Use Mysql JOIN on column value as column name with another table column name

Tags: php, mysql, join, multiple-columns

I want to use a table's column value as column name and use it as JOIN ON value with another table column name. Below is my query.

```
SELECT nid, sid, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN cid = 2 THEN data END) first_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cid = 3 THEN data END) last_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cid = 4 THEN data END) email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cid = 5 THEN data END) phone_number,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cid = 6 THEN data END) transitions,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cid = 7 THEN data END) **upload**,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cid = 9 THEN data END) coupon_code
  FROM wsd AS wsd JOIN files AS fm ON **upload** = fm.fid WHERE nid IN(66,67) GROUP BY sid
```

As you see the above code, I want to use upload column as the JOIN on another table. Also, is it possible to embed HTML tags on the results?

Comment: You should take a look at order of query execution to get idea why you can't reference alias in join clause in query like yours. https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution

Comment: The question seems to be in two parts. If so, I don't understand the first part.

Comment: Can you post the table structure and some insert queries to have some test data? Cheers

Comment: @Ognj3n, thanks. Ok instead of alias, how to use the column value as column name to use it as join ON

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the results using temporary table. Here is my answer.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_temp_table SELECT sid, cid, data FROM wsd WHERE cid = 7 AND nid IN (66,67);
SELECT wsd.nid, wsd.sid, fm.filename, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 2 THEN wsd.data END) fn,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 3 THEN wsd.data END) ln,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 4 THEN wsd.data END) email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 5 THEN wsd.data END) ph,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 6 THEN wsd.data END) tr,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 7 THEN wsd.data END) upr,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 9 THEN wsd.data END) coc
  FROM wsd wsd JOIN my_temp_table ON wsd.sid = my_temp_table.sid JOIN files fm ON my_temp_table.data = fm.fid WHERE nid IN(66,67) GROUP BY wsd.sid;
```

Instead of temporary table, better query as follows:

```
SELECT wsd.nid, wsd.sid, fm.filename, 
           MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 2 THEN wsd.data END) fn,
           MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 3 THEN wsd.data END) ln,
           MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 4 THEN wsd.data END) email,
           MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 5 THEN wsd.data END) ph,
           MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 6 THEN wsd.data END) tr,
           MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 7 THEN wsd.data END) upr,
           MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 9 THEN wsd.data END) coc
      FROM wsd wsd LEFT JOIN files fm ON wsd.data = fm.fid WHERE nid IN(66,67) GROUP BY wsd.sid;
```